# start date issue for razorpay subscription link

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, datetime, razorpay

I have created an API that creates a `Razorpay` subscription link, however
I get the following error- `Subscription's start time is past the current time. Cannot do an auth transaction now` when I try test payment using `Razorpay` subscription link.

Note- A `start_at` and `expire_by` needs to be a timestamp, in Unix format.
start date- is the current date and time
end date-1 day from current date and time

Sample code-

```
let day = new Date();
day.setSeconds(day.getSeconds() + 30)
let today = moment(day);
      
let nextDay = new Date(day);
nextDay.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);
let tommorow = moment(nextDay);

let start_date = today.tz('Asia/Kolkata')
let start_at = moment(start_date).format("X");

let expire_date = tommorow.tz('Asia/Kolkata');
let expire_by = moment(expire_date).format("X");

let body = {
    plan_id:PLANID,
    total_count:1200,
    quantity:1,
    start_at:start_at,
    expire_by:expire_by
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know why you're using a library for this. ECMAScript dates use UTC ms as the time value and the same epoch as UNIX, so the "UNIX time" for now is just `Date.now() / 1000`. Adding 30 seconds is then just adding 30, adding a UTC day is just adding 8.64e4 seconds (since UTC days are always 24 hours long). Perhaps the API wants UNIX time in milliseconds, not seconds?

Comment: Checking the [*subscription API docs*](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/subscriptions/#create-a-subscription) it seems seconds is the required unit. It seems you can omit the *start_at* value to start the subscription immediately.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the update, Now I try to calculate expire date --> let expire_by = Math.round((Date.now() / 1000) + 8.64e4);  however I get the following error end_time must be between 946684800 and 4765046400. Can you please check if that the right way to convert, Thanks.

Comment: At the moment (6 Aug 2021), `Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) + 8.64e4` returns something like 1628334311 which is between 946684800 (1 Jan 2000) and 4765046400 (31 Dec 2120), so the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I figured out, Razorpay support subscription payment years upto 2099, I then reduce the total count , It worked. @RobG Thanks a lot